# Integrate with SymPy in Julia

Tags: julia

I am a newcomer to Julia.
I have tried:

```
@syms x t
integrate( t^(x-1*exp(-t), (t,0,Inf) )
```

Which is the definition of the gamma function.
The output is:

```
silly factor * (g(x,0) - g(x,Inf) ).
```

The "silly factor" is

```
x*Gamma(x)/Gamma(x-1)
```

which cancels to 1.

Actually Julia does this with `simplify` in the next line.
But the Latin g is actually a Greek g.
And this I don't understand.
Any insight would be appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: Sympy variables often render in a latex like format. This isn't something sympy.jl touches. You can live with it or use other names, though in this case it seems like a built in.

Comment: Thank you, what I mean is the output should simply be Gamma(x) preferably in perfect LaTex.

Comment: Try using the symbolic infinity `oo` and not the numeric one `Inf`. Then you get the answer you want, though it depends on the value of `x`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works as expected. At least nearly. It gives a conditional expression with gamma(x) for x>1. But gamma(x) is defined for all reals except non positive Integers. I'll going on exploring Julia.

Comment: That's certainly true mathematically, but the integral itself isn't how the gamma function is defined for other value of `x`. Anyways, have fun with Julia.